# NumPy: Finding minimum in submatrices/blocks and corresponding row, column indices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given a square matrix M (mxm), composed of submatrices of dimension (nxn), where mxm modulo nxn == 0, return a matrix of all  minima from each submatrix.

e.g. M: (4x4)

```
M = array([[19834, 29333, 29333, 33120],
           [ 5148, 25560, 29393,  8083],
           [ 5148, 29393, 25560,  8083],
           [19958, 25748, 25748, 24506]], dtype=uint64)
```

Each submatrix m is 2x2, with minima returned as follows:

```
M* = array([[ 5148, 8083],
            [ 5148, 8083]], dtype=uint64)
```

I've tried to reshape the arrays and invoke min(), but it only allows you to do so across one axis.

Additionally I'd like to get the original index of the minima as well, but I've assumed I'd have to search for it after generating M*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the two axes into two more resulting in a `4D` array with a length of `2` each as the second one of those two split axes, which would be the second and fourth axes in the resulting `4D` array. Then, simply find `minimum` along those two axes for the desired output.

Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
m,n = M.shape
out = M.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2).min(axis=(1,3))
```

Sample run -

```
In [41]: M
Out[41]: 
array([[33, 26, 15, 53, 72, 53],
       [12, 64, 28, 27, 58, 51],
       [61, 42, 70, 92, 61, 95],
       [35, 62, 48, 27, 53, 33]])

In [42]: m,n = M.shape

In [43]: M.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2).min(axis=(1,3))
Out[43]: 
array([[12, 15, 51],
       [35, 27, 33]])
```

---

**Getting `argmins` in each submatrix corresponding to original array**

For getting those argmins, we need to do some additional work as listed below -

```
B = 2 # Blocksize 
m,n = M.shape

# Reshape into 4D array as discussed for the previous problem
M4D = M.reshape(m//B,B,n//B,B)

# Bring the second and fourth axes together and then merge.
# Then, get linear indices within each submatrix
lidx = M4D.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(-1,n//B,B**2).argmin(-1)

# Convert those linear indices into row, col indices corresponding
# to submatrix and finally corresponding to the original array
r,c = np.unravel_index(lidx,[B,B])
row = r + (B*np.arange(m//B)[:,None])
col = c + B*np.arange(n//B)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [170]: M
Out[170]: 
array([[40, 91, 90, 72, 86, 44],
       [63, 56, 20, 95, 60, 41],
       [28, 50, 32, 89, 69, 46],
       [41, 41, 33, 81, 30, 63]])

In [171]: np.column_stack((row.ravel(),col.ravel()))
Out[171]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: is it possible to get the 'local' coordinates of the minima with respect to each 2x2 submatrix? Thus the coordinates of the minima at M[1, 5], would be (1,1). ps thank you for all your amazing help and insights.

Comment: @user1658296 That would be `r,c`.

Comment: I see. I think I should update the question (?), because what I'm ultimately looking for is a set of tuples of the form (instrinsic-coords, local-coords, minima). e.g. for minima M[1, 5], local-coords are (1,1), and instrinsic-coords are (0,2). So: ((0, 2), (1,1), 41)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work making use of `np.hsplit` and `np.vsplit`.

Since `map` in python3 returns `map object`, it is necessary to listify the result of map before further calculation.

Edit: For the second problem, changing `np.min` into `np.argmin` will result in a matrix of positions.

```
import numpy as np

M_star = np.array(list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda x: np.min(x), x)), list(map(lambda x: np.hsplit(x, n), np.vsplit(M, n))))))
M_star_pos = np.array(list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda x: np.argmin(x), x)), list(map(lambda x: np.hsplit(x, n), np.vsplit(M, n))))))
```